# Understanding the input specifications for a laptop adapter

Tags: voltage, current, adapter, input

The sticker on my laptop adapter claims the input should be

> INPUT: 100-240V~ 2.5A(2,5A) 50-60Hz

What does all this mean?  Here are a couple specific questions:

1. Can the adapter accept anywhere between 100V to 240V?!
2. Is there a problem with plugging this adapter into an outlet labeled
   "2A max"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means that the laptop requires an input alternating voltage ranging from 100V to 240V, with frequency ranging from 50Hz to 60Hz.

Maximum required current is 2.5A at both the ends of the voltage input range so yes, a 2A outlet is not enough. A breaker might trip or the wires can catch fire, you better use another outlet.

Comment: If the outlet reads "2A max", I thought that meant that the laptop would never be able to draw more than 2A.  How then would a breaker trip?

Comment: That's the point. The laptop would require more than the max thus letting the breaker trip

Comment: In reality, I plugged my laptop into the outlet and it seemed to work fine.  Does that mean I was lucky that the breaker did not trip?  It seems there is no risk to the laptop either way, correct?

Comment: There is no risk for the laptop, if the breaker did not trip that might be because there is no breaker.

Comment: 2.5A is only 25% more than 2A. That's probably not enough difference to be noticed by most overload detection systems. 2A is a VERY small rating - usually for something like electric shaver outlets in washrooms. These may have an internal isolating transformer which can be overloaded by excessive current.